# I believe I made an infinite loop and I don't know where it's being created

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm attempting to practice arrays by creating something where a user can create the list of items for a shop. I want the item names to go to a list box and an array that will be parallel to an array that holds the price and quantity of the item. I also want the user to be able to check the price and quantity of the item by selecting the item in the list box and pressing the check item button. The program crashes when I attempt to use the check item button.

Here is the part where the user adds in their item.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    addName = InputBox("What is the name of the product you wish to add?")
    addPrice = InputBox("What is the price of the product?")
    addQuantity = InputBox("What is the quantity in stock of the product?")
    lstStock.Items.Add(addName)
End Sub
```

I added the items into the array and I hope I set it up to where it will automatically create the array regardless of length. I believe this may be creating an infinite loop that freezes the program.

```
Public Sub added(ByRef addlist As String, ByRef addPQ As String)
    Dim nameID As Double = lstStock.Items.Count
    Dim lstCount As Double = lstStock.Items.Count
    Dim lstArrayCount As Double = 0
    Dim num As Double
    Dim lstNum As String
    While lstArrayCount < 1
        lstNum = addName
        lstArrayCount = +1
    End While
    While lstArrayCount < lstCount
        lstNum = lstNum & addName & "}, {"
        lstArrayCount = +1
    End While
    Dim priceQuantityCount As Double
    Dim lstPrice As String
    While priceQuantityCount < 1
        lstPrice = lstPrice & addPrice & ", " & addQuantity & "}"
        priceQuantityCount = +1
    End While
    While priceQuantityCount > 1 And priceQuantityCount < lstCount
        lstPrice = lstPrice & ", {" & addPrice & ", " & addQuantity & "}"
        priceQuantityCount = +1
    End While
    Dim List() As String = {lstNum}
    Dim PriceQuantity(,) As String = {{lstPrice}}
    addlist = List.ToString()
    addPQ = PriceQuantity.ToString()
End Sub
```

everything freezes when the button is pressed. I put this bit in here just in case. Nothing visual happens except the program freezes and the cpu usage jumps up. No error messages or anything like that.

```
Private Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    Dim check As String = lstStock.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim add1 As String
    Dim add2 As String
    added(add1, add2)
    Dim strPrice As String
    Dim strQuantity As String
    Dim PQArray As String
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    PQArray = add2
    intIndex = PQArray.IndexOf("")
    If intIndex <> -1 Then
        strPrice = PQArray.Substring(0, intIndex)
        strQuantity = PQArray.Substring(intIndex + 1)
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("there are " & "quantity" & " " & check & " in stock priced at $" & "price" & " each.")
    MessageBox.Show(strPrice & "  :  " & strQuantity)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Please don't just post all your code and expect us to sort it out. You need to identify the relevant code and post just that. Also, a crash is an unhandled exception so you need to tell us what the error message is, where exactly it occurred and what data was in use at the time. The debugger provides you with all that information and you can find out more by setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code line by line. You must ALWAYS have used the debugger to its fullest BEFORE posting here. If you need to learn how to debug, you can search for that information on the web.

Comment: sorry about that, I'm relatively new to this site and am still getting used to everything. I've edited it, hopefully that helps. If there's anything else I can help with I will.

Comment: I would recommend, unless you've got a very specific requirement to use Arrays, don't. Lists are just a whole lot more pleasant to use.  In your example here, you could have a list of a custom class which holds all info about the shop item  including the name, price and quantity as a single unit.  Can do that with arrays I know, but lists are just easy

Comment: In the first code snippet, you are getting three values from the user and adding one to a `ListBox` but you don't add anything to any arrays. The whole point of concurrent arrays is that the values at the same index in multiple arrays is related, so you need to add related values to multiple arrays at the same index.

Comment: Thank you Hursey I'm trying to get better at arrays and that is why I am specifically using them.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think I understand but like I said I am new and trying to learn how this all works. So if I am understanding you correctly, I have no connection between what the user enters and the arrays I'm trying to create? Does this mean I have to move the portion of code that controls the creation of the array?

Comment: One of the reasons beginners have issues is because they try to do too many things at once and fail at all of them because they cannot see the wood for the trees. If you want to learn how to use arrays then use arrays. `ListBoxes` should not even come into it. get rid of everything that is not directly related to those arrays. Create three arrays and, each time you get the three inputs, put one in each array. You can then get the data out of the arrays by index, confirming that the related data is indeed at the same index. Once you can do the arrays properly, then you can bring in `ListBoxes`.

Comment: Ill keep trying, thanks anyways. Im not one to quit, it will just take me a little longer to figure it out. I've tried looking most of the things up but it can be hard to sort through all of the information being spewed at you. But tedious tasks are usually the most beneficial so ill have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the three arrays.

A Name array. This will be persisted in the list box itself. The `ListBox.Items` is an array of Object.

A Price array at the Form level. This should be of type `Decimal` - good to use for money things.

```
Private PriceArray(10) As Decimal
```

A Quantity array at the Form level. This should be of type Integer, whole numbers of in stock items.

```
Private QuantityArray(10) As Integer
```

Now let's look at your Add method.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim addName = InputBox("What is the name of the product you wish to add?")
    Dim addPrice = InputBox("What is the price of the product?")
    Dim addQuantity = InputBox("What is the quantity in stock of the product?")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(addName)
    PriceArray(CurrentIndex) = CDec(addPrice)
    QuantityArray(CurrentIndex) = CInt(addQuantity)
    CurrentIndex += 1
End Sub
```

I changed your 3 variables to local variables (added Dim). I changed the name of the listbox so it would work in my test project. I added the Name to the list box just as you did. The first time this button is clicked the name is add to the Items collection at index 0. I added another form level variable, `CurrentIndex`. This will keep track of where we are in the arrays. The first time through `CurrentIndex` is initialized by default to `0`. We use Current Index as the index where we fill in the inputted value. Next time we add we need to increment `CurrentIndex` to the next index.

```
CurrentIndex += 1
```

I think you tried to do this but you had the syntax a bit wrong. It is += ; you had = +1 which will just assign 1 to the variable.

Let's think where we are. The name in the list box has an index that matches the index in the price array and the quantity array. The arrays are parallel (concurrent).

To get the information back from our arrays I used the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim IndexSelected = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    TextBox1.Text = PriceArray(IndexSelected).ToString("N2")
    TextBox2.Text = QuantityArray(IndexSelected).ToString
End Sub
```

We can get the index with the `.SelectedIndex` property. We use that index to find the matching values in the `PriceArray` and the `QuantityArray`. The `"N2"` after `.ToString` for the `PriceArray` tells it to display a number with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Oh... that makes a bit more sense. I will check back to this in the morning and see if I can get it set up properly. And I wouldn’t have ever caught that syntax error if not for you. Thanks a ton!